# How does wrapping a c++ boost serializer as a boost python module change the way of serialization?

Tags: python, c++, serialization, boost

I am trying to interchange data from a C++ process to a Python process. For that I am using the boost.serialization library and it worked totally fine to serialize and deserialize between two C++ processes in the simple text format.

Now, to access the serialized data from Python side, I am using the boost.python library. I wrap the serialization code up to a Python module, which also works perfectly fine. Serializing the data in a text archive from inside the python environment and loading it from there again works. But loading from Python side the data from the text archive that was created by a C++ process brought me a `RuntimeError: input stream error`. This is because it expected a different format (see below).

I am using this `gps_position` class from the boost.serialization tutorial "A very simple case":

```
class gps_position {
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & degrees;
        ar & minutes;
        ar & seconds;
    }
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;

public:
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
        degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
    {}
};
```

I use these `save` and `load` functions:

```
void save(){
    std::cout << "save()" << std::endl;
    std::ofstream ofs("archive");
    gps_position g(35, 59, 24.567f);
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << g;
    }
}

void load(){
    std::cout << "load()" << std::endl;
    gps_position newg;
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("archive");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> newg;
    }
}
```

And this is the boost.python wrapping code:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
    boost::python::def("save", &save);
    boost::python::def("load", &load);
}
```

[1] This is the content of the text archive file from C++ side:

```
22 serialization::archive 17 22 serialization::archive 17 0 0 35 59 2.456699944e+01
```

[2] And the text archive file from the same serialization method, but as explained wrapped up as Python module and called from the interactive Python environment:

```
0 0 35 59 2.456699944e+01
```

I learned that `22 serialization::archive 17` describes the signature of the archive file. But why do I have it in [1] two times? And why in [2] not even once? I could just ignore the signatures (it works then), but I want to understand why wrapping up the code changes the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why two times?
   The "text_archive" writes the signature to the output stream when it is constructed, but it also writes the signature again when the archive is finished. In fact, the signature is used to indicate the beginning and end of the archive.
2. Why zero times?
   When the serialization code is wrapped as a Python module, it is actually the *boost.python* library that is doing the (de)serialization instead of *boost.serialization*.
   *boost.python* uses Python's built-in ***pickle*** module to (de)serialize objects, which is a completely different serialization format, not compatible with *boost.serialization*'s text archive format.
   Moreover, when you create the archive file, it does not include the signature metadata, simply 'cause it is not necessary for Python's deserialization process.

In general, to ensure that archives are saved and loaded using the same serialization method, you may choose JSON, that that is compatible for both C++ and Python environments.